# Generating a new Oauth2 token from REST ASSURED

Tags: rest-assured

I am trying to generate an Oauth2 token using REST Assured API. Below is my code. I am not sure how to generate it because I am getting an invalid response when the below code is run.

```java
given().          
    .relaxedHTTPSValidation()            
    .redirects().follow(false)        
    .param("Auth URL", "https://example.com/identity/oauth/token")
    .param("Access Token URL", "https://example2.com/identity/oauth/token")
    .param("Client ID", "kumar")
    .param("Client Secret", "kumar1")
    .param("Scope", "SUBSCRIPTION_ALL")
    .param("Grant Type", "Client Credentials")
    .auth()
    .preemptive().basic("kumar", "kumar1")
    .when()
    .redirects().follow(false)
    .get("https://MainURI.com/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=read");

System.out.println(tokenResp.asString());
```

Response:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://example.com/404/index.html">here</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement Custom Authentication and add them in filter like:

```
given().
        filter((requestSpec, responseSpec, ctx) -> {
            // Your code for generating token using OAuth
            String header = //Your service call
            requestSpec.header("AUTH", header );
            return ctx.next(requestSpec, responseSpec);
        }).
when().
        get("/customAuth").
then().
  statusCode(200);
```